# Pause the rendering/refreshing/drawing of the gVim/Vim screen

Tags: gvim, vim-windows, window-management

I am developing a gVim plugin that manages/reorganizes panels, buffers and tabs.

However, while most programmatic re-arranging take milliseconds, they can still look very messy to the eyes while you see re-positionings, resizings, etc take place. Specially the more complex ones.

So, my question: is there a way to programaticaly pause gVim from rendering/refreshing/showing changes to the screen and then also grammatically unpause it?

If not natively, are there any workarounds?

My main focus gVim, but if a solution is only possible for Vim, I can live with that too.

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you provided enough information so others could reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
set lazyredraw
```

Remark: in my experience it has only an effect on Vim and not on gVim.